# My sum function does not sum values of some columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe, that has some columns with calculated values or values from input:

```
Data = {'name':  ['a', 'b'],
        'number1': [5, 3],
        'number2': [3, 2]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns = ['name','number1', 'number2'])
```

Then I write my total function like this(nevermind adding up the names for now):

```
df.loc['Grand Total']=df.sum()
```

And if I calculate some more columns AFTER adding my `Grand total` row, they get their `Grand total` value too:

```
df['number3'] = df['number2'] * 2
```

But the problem comes when I want to add any columns that have been parsed from a table in some excel file:

```
excelFile = pd.ExcelFile("my_excel_file.xlsx")
nrows = excelFile.book.sheet_by_index(2).nrows
values_from_Excel= excelFile.parse(2, skiprows=1, skipfooter= nrows-(8)).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
values_from_Excel = pd.DataFrame(
    {'name': values_from_Excel.iloc[:, 1].tolist(),
     'number4': values_from_Excel.iloc[:, 11].tolist()
    })

df = pd.merge(df, values_from_Excel, on='name', how='left')
```

After merging this column to df, `Grand total` value for `number4` is not calculated... What is the problem here..?

Comment: dtypes of calculated columns are `int`, while dtype of stubborn column is `numpy.int64`

Answer (score 0):

Assign it again after all of the code (with `axis=1`):

```
...
df.loc['Grand Total']=df.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: I does not work... the `Grand  total` value is still `NaN`

Comment: @milka1117 Try now